# Flot with json and php

Tags: php, json, mysqli, flot

I made a json array with php. It works but it gives only the 'data' result from the first label and not the rest. Beside that it starts everytime with a number. How can i fix this?

```
    $sql = $site->mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, event_start_date FROM events");
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())   {

        $dataset[] = array('label' => $row['title']);

        $sql2 = $site->mysqli->query("SELECT timestamp, event_id, COUNT(timestamp) AS row_count FROM order_products WHERE event_id = '".$row['id']."' GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))");
        $count2 = $sql2->num_rows;
        while($row2 = $sql2->fetch_assoc())   {

            $dataset['data'][] = array(intval($row2['timestamp'] * 1000), (int)$row2['row_count']);

        }

    }
    $results[]=$dataset;

die(Json_encode($results));
```

Result:

```
    [{"0":{"label":"Label 1"},"data":[[1392894348000,10],                   
        [1392998502000,3],[1393066962000,5],[1393262541000,3],          
        [1393577348000,5],[1393704543000,2],[1393780878000,1],
        [1393882353000,3],"1":{"label":"Label 2"},"2":{"label":"Label 3"}}]
```

Comment: Given your current result, what is your desired result layout? all your `data` is in the same array, as you are doing `$dataset['data'][] =...`. Also, instead of a nested query, you could do this in 1 query using a `JOIN`

Comment: This line make your array starts every time using number: `$dataset[] = array('label' => $row['title']);`

Comment: The result is good beside the: `{"0":` etc. And the most important part is that It gives no results for the rest of the labels. The output gives only data for Label 1 but in the database there is also data for Label 2 and label 3 but it doesn't show this.

Comment: When i replace  `$dataset[]` and `$dataset['data'][]` for an echo, then i get a the correct output put i want it in a array. So i gues it has to be something with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should empty your `$dataset` for each event:

```
$sql = $site->mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, event_start_date FROM events");
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())   {

    $dataset = array('label' => $row['title'], 'data' => array());

    $sql2 = $site->mysqli->query("SELECT timestamp, event_id, COUNT(timestamp) AS row_count FROM order_products WHERE event_id = '".$row['id']."' GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))");
    $count2 = $sql2->num_rows;
    while($row2 = $sql2->fetch_assoc())   {

        $dataset['data'][] = array(intval($row2['timestamp'] * 1000), (int)$row2['row_count']);

    }
    $results[]=$dataset;
}

die(json_encode($results));
```